# CICD Yaml in Azure Devops for : dotnet6 project with some WebJobs into AppService in Azure

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-webjobs

I have a dotnet6 project which I want to deploy on a AppService in Azure.
I am using Auzre Devops for my CICD and there I'm using a Yaml file for build and later deployment.
I have also some WebJobs that I want to deploy on the same AppService in the same slot.
The build process of my solution will provide a zip file with some files:

> 1- zip file
> 2- Parameters.xml
> 3- SetParameters.xml
> 4- readme.txt
> 5- and a deploy.cmd file which is a Batch file

This is the task for building a solution:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'Mydea/Mydea.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\yourProject.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    clean: true
```

Later in CD I use another command to deploy my zip file into the Azure like this:

```
- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy WebApp'
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'xxxx'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'xxx'
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    ResourceGroupName: 'xxxx'
    SlotName: 'Test'
    packageForLinux: '$(pipeline.workspace)/drop/WebApp.zip'
    JSONFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
```

until here is everything fine.

But if I want to deploy some WebJob, it is different. I will not have a zip file with some batch, the only thing that I need here is a zip file which directing to the correct path:
App_Data/jobs/triggered/yourproject

later in the CD you need to call the same task in order to deploy your Webjobs.

Problem:
I can create 2 seperate zip file in the same artifact and later in CD, I need to call the deploy task. But the deploy task only can get one zip file.
If you calling the deploy task 2 times it will override it. that means you can have only your project deployed or your webjobs.

My idea was to combine the two zip files in the CI like this:

```
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: 'xxx/xxx.sln'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
    clean: true

- task: ExtractFiles@1
  inputs:
    archiveFilePatterns: '$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip'
    destinationFolder: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/root'
    cleanDestinationFolder: true
    overwriteExistingFiles: true

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'publish Webjob Daily'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: 'xxx/xxx.Webjob.Daily/xxx.Webjob.Daily.csproj'
    arguments: '--output $(Build.BinariesDirectory)/root/App_Data/jobs/triggered/WebjobDaily'
    zipAfterPublish: false
    modifyOutputPath: false

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Zip solution'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)/root'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/WebApp.zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  displayName: Publish drop Artifact
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifact: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

As you can see in this tasks, I combine the 2 zip files into one zip file.
notice that the zip file for the main solution has also some extra files with one batch file.

I tried to deploy this zip file in CD, the main project was successfully deployed but not the WebJobs.

If I deploy only the main project or only the WebJobs, it will be successfully done. but I need  to deploy both of them togehter.

Now for me the last way is to create for my project another slot in the AppService. and deploy the main project on one Slot and the WebJobs on the other and this will work.
But this is not a clean solution.
I like to have them both in the same Slot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
In the deployment you should have two separate zip files one for your WebApp and the other for your WebJobs, exactly like the code in my question.

In the deployment you should call the `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4` task two times, first for your WebApp and after that for your WebJobs.

But...
in order that the second task doesn't override the first task you should alter 2 other parameters; `enableCustomDeployment` to true and `ExcludeFilesFromAppDataFlag` to false.

```
                - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
                  displayName: 'Deploy WebApp'
                  inputs:
                    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                    azureSubscription: 'xxx'
                    appType: 'webApp'
                    WebAppName: 'xxx'
                    deployToSlotOrASE: true
                    ResourceGroupName: 'xxx'
                    SlotName: 'Test'
                    packageForLinux: '$(pipeline.workspace)/drop/WebApp.zip'
                    JSONFiles: '**/appsettings.json'

                - task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
                  displayName: 'Deploy Webjobs'
                  inputs:
                    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
                    azureSubscription: 'xxx'
                    appType: 'webApp'
                    WebAppName: 'xxx'
                    deployToSlotOrASE: true
                    ResourceGroupName: 'xxx'
                    SlotName: 'Test'
                    packageForLinux: '$(pipeline.workspace)/drop/Webjobs.zip'
                    JSONFiles: '**/appsettings.json'
                    enableCustomDeployment: true
                    ExcludeFilesFromAppDataFlag: false
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't combine the two artifacts into the same zip file. Reason being is how will platform know to split the zip file once it's extracted?

Doing a CI pipeline that builds the artifacts is certainly plausible, but why not have two different CD's that are triggered by the CI pipeline. Each separate CD will pull their respective artifact. Going this route does two things;

1. Doesn't overly complicate the CD pipeline with additional logic to handle two different artifacts, thereby keeping things clean and separated, and
2. If you ever decided to run your WebJob on a different app service (plan), you can easily change the deployment target.